# Find the position of first ' space lower case alphabet' in a string - Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, databricks

I have an entry in a table as below

> - MasterCard recurrent=true renewal=true s
> - Visa initialCharge=true moneyBacks=82518
> - Visa paymentMethodFailed=true renewal=tr

Is there a way to find out the position of a pattern such as 'space first_lower_case_alphabet'
i.e

- for string 'MasterCard recurrent=true renewal=true s' I want to find
  the position of ' recurrent'
- for string 'Visa initialCharge=true
  moneyBacks=82518' I want to find the position of ' initialCharge'

I tried the following code but it does not work. The output is always 0

```
CHARINDEX('%[^ a-z]%', col_name)
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need another regular expression. Try the following with `regexp_extract` function:

`SELECT regexp_extract(col_name, '\s[a-z]+', 1);`

Then you can use this result in `charindex` function as following:

`SELECT CHARINDEX(regexp_extract(col_name, '\s[a-z]+', 1), col_name)`

See more in here: [databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/regexp_extract.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! The above code throws the following error 'IllegalArgumentException: Regex group count is 0, but the specified group index is 1'

Comment: Have you tried putting 0 instead of 1 in `regexp_extract()`?